# Rendering unicode characters correctly on textbox

Tags: c++, unicode, wxwidgets

I am working on a translation application in which users are allowed to give English input and I need to convert to a target language and display on a text box. I am facing problems in displaying unicode characters.

Complex characters are not rendering correctly. I know windows uses *Uniscribe* for rendering complex characters. So do I need to use that explicitly to get the correct rendering? What is the equivalent of Uniscribe in LINUX and MAC?

I am using C++ with wxWidgets framework and trying to display unicode characters on a text box. Any help would be great!

Comment: Your wxWidgets lib is compiled as unicode, right?

Comment: Yes. It is compiled as unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that Uniscribe support in wxWidgets was merely a [Google Summer of code idea this year](http://www.nabble.com/wxWidgets-and-Google-Summer-of-Code-2009-td22596235.html), it seems unlikely that it's working today.

There's no trivial Linux or Mac equivalent for Uniscribe

Comment: Thanks. If there is no equivalent in Linux, how do programs like web browsers render properly? I am bit confused.

Comment: I don't know for sure. Obviously, one alternative would be to do so themselves - just give the OS a bitmap to draw instead of a string. But as far as I know, one other common alternative is to just not render complex scripts at all. Mind you, simple stuff like Chinese doesn't require Uniscribe, that's just a matter of a proper font. The real complex stuff happens with e.g. Arabic or Tamil, where letter shapes depend on the surrounding text. That's what Uniscribe is for.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on Pango. It's the library that supports full OpenType rendering on Linux. Mac's another story.